# Vuetify DarkMode colors wrong after page reload

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, darkmode

My Vuetify App now can correctly toggle to darkmode (hooray!) however, when a full page refresh occurs, the style colors do not change (my primary color is kept from the light mode)

I can toggle to light, then back to dark, and the colors shift correctly to the dark theme's colors.

**net-net**
what is going on? from what i am reading, all i need to do is set this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true in the app mounted method, but it doesn't work...

**UPDATE**
we are using a nuxt layout, and setting the dark = true on the vuetify theme:

```
  mounted() {
    console.log('darkMode:', this.darkMode);
    this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.darkMode;
  },
```

Comment: you wanna set default mode after refresh?
if you wanna set default mode after a refresh, you need to set `darkMode` into vuex and you use `darkMode`.because after a refresh, restore variables into vuex.

Comment: yeah, I am setting `this.$vuetify.theme.dark = this.darkMode;` into our main-layout.vue component, and its setting the background and button colors, but the text colors are not changing until i toggle this.$vuetify.theme.dark off and on again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some digging, found that this is a known issue with the darkmode vuetify meta data:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13378

**Update:**
the git hub issue was closed, but the expected workaround did not work for me.

I ended up throwing a half millisecond setTimeout to reset the `this.$vuetify.theme.dark = true` due to the meta code changing it again to false midway through the darkmode being applied.